# How to get a Terminator Layout Command to show up in history?

Tags: bash, command-history, gnome-terminator

I've discovered the joy saving Terminator layouts and adding commands to `~/.config/terminator/config` that are run when it starts up. I've also discovered that hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to stop a watch command for a moment can't be followed by an up arrow to restart the watch because the command isn't in the history.

Here's an ugly work around that only prints the command:

```
command = (set -x; watch "date") && bash || bash
```

This allows copying the command after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> but who has time for that? I want my up arrow to work. Hoping some bash magic can fix this.

Using terminator 1.91 in RHEL

Comment: Do the startup commands run as your user? My hunch is that they're run as someone else, hence why they don't show up in your history. Would research myself but gotta leave the house now, let me know and I'll try to help out later

Comment: Note that this will be quite tricky as the commands are run in a non-interactive shell which means history is disabled by default. You can try to enable it but even then you would need to explicitly read the history into the new bash shell you start after killing `watch` before using it.

Comment: @ajmeese7 no, they are run by the right user but history is not enabled in non-interactive shells so they aren't kept in the history. I've been playing with calling the command in an interactive shell and writing the history (command=`bash -ic 'watch date; history -a; bash'`) and then setting `PROMPT_COMMAND` to `history -r` to read it in the new shell but I can't get it to work.

Comment: @Terdon I’ll take a reasonable work around.

Comment: I hear you, I wish I could offer one. None of the things I tried worked, I only mentioned some of the approaches I looked at in case someone smarter can make them work. Sorry :/

Comment: @terdon I may have found something. I'd welcome a review.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to do what I want:

```
command = watch date && echo "watch date" >> ~/.bash_history && bash || bash
```

Inspired by [How to add a command to the history when it is run inside of a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45016550/how-to-add-a-command-to-the-history-when-it-is-run-inside-of-a-bash-script)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the need to repeat the command put this in `~/.config/terminator/config`

```
command = '''bash -ic 'histrun '\''watch "date"'\''''''
```

and this in `.bash_rc`

```
histrun() {
  eval $1 && printf '%s\n' "$1" >> ~/.bash_history && bash || bash
}
```

If you have a different command (date in this example) that you don't want run right away but want available in history as soon as you hit `ctrl-c` then use this:

```
command = '''bash -ic 'histhold '\''date'\''''''
```

with this:

```
histhold() {
  printf '%s\n' "$1" && (watch cat) && printf '%s\n' "$1" >> ~/.bash_history && bash || bash
}
```